# jqGrid table untidy in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, jqgrid

I created a jqGrid table which looks as as expected in Chrome but is untidy in Mozilla Firefox. See screenshots and code below. After reload or sort in Firefox it renders correctly. Does anyone know how to correct the initial rendering in Firefox?

**Interface in Chrome** 
[image]

**Interface in Mozilla Firefox (before reload or sort)**
[image]

**Code**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $('#tbl_name').jqGrid('autoWidthColumns').jqGrid({
    url:'GRID/grid_manageProvinsi_data.php?type=provinsi',
    datatype: 'json',
    colNames:['Action','Provinsi','Harga (Untuk Pengiriman Barang)','Terakhir di Update','Updater'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'action',index:'action', width:30, align:'center', sortable:false, search:false, searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','cn']}},
        {name:'nama_prov',index:'nama_prov', width:80, align:'left', sortable:true, search:true, searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','cn']}},
        {name:'harga',index:'harga', width:80, align:'center', sortable:true, search:true, searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','cn']}},
        {name:'last_update',index:'last_update', width:120, align:'center', search:true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq','ne','lt','le','gt','ge'], dataInit: function (elem) { $(elem).datepicker({ showButtonPanel: true }) } }, align:'center'},
        {name:'email',index:'email', width:50, align:'left', search:true, searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','cn']}}                     
    ],
    pager: '#tbl_name_pager',
    rowNum: 30,
    rowList: [10, 20, 30],
    sortname: 'nama_prov',
    sortorder: 'asc',
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    caption: 'Manage Provinsi',
    width: $(window).width() - 275,
    height: $(window).height() - 230,
    rownumbers: true,  
    loadComplete: function () {
        $(this).find('>tbody>tr.jqgrow:odd').addClass('myAltRowClassEven');
        $(this).find('>tbody>tr.jqgrow:even').addClass('myAltRowClassOdd');
    }

  });
  jQuery('#tbl_name').jqGrid('navGrid','#tbl_name_pager',{edit:false,add:false,del:false},
                                {}, // edit options
                                {}, // add options
                                {}, //del options
                                {multipleSearch:true,width:400});

});
```

Comment: If you could reproduce your issue online (e.g. in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)) you would make people's task easier to provide you with a working solution.

Comment: Improved wording and formatting. Could be further improved by adding a jsfiddle as requested.

Comment: It seems that you use my plugin [jQuery.jqGrid.autoWidthColumns.js](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid-plugins), which I wrote **before** I started to develop  [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). Free jqGrid contains auto-djustment featues described in [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Auto-adjustment-of-the-width-of-column). I recommend you to migrate from the usage of `autoWidthColumns` to the latest (4.10.x) version of free jqGrid.